# Dynamic Expandable Recyclerview List Failing

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm new to Android and I know this might be a piece of cake but I'm struggling.

I was trying to create a dynamic expandable recycler view using firebase realtime database but the data is not displaying properly.

I'm passing a string from one activity to another and comparing the string to the database field and then displaying it's child components but I don't know where I'm failing.

I want to display the Parent and child field by comparing the name field with the value.

```
  @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_course_detail);
        //string value from another activity
        String value = getIntent().getExtras().getString("name");

        recycler_view = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recycler_expand);
        recycler_view.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));

        FirebaseDatabase database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();

        DatabaseReference parentReference = database.getReference().child("Tutors");
        //comparing
        parentReference.equalTo(value).addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                final List<ParentList> Parent = new ArrayList<>();
                for (final DataSnapshot snapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()){


                    final String ParentKey = snapshot.getKey().toString();

                    snapshot.child("title").getValue();

                    DatabaseReference childReference =
                            FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child(ParentKey);
                    childReference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                            final List<ChildList> Child = new ArrayList<>();


                            for (DataSnapshot snapshot1:dataSnapshot.getChildren())
                            {
                                final String ChildValue =  snapshot1.getValue().toString();

                                snapshot1.child("title").getValue();

                                Child.add(new ChildList(ChildValue));

                            }

                            Parent.add(new ParentList(ParentKey, Child));

                            DocExpandableRecyclerAdapter adapter = new DocExpandableRecyclerAdapter(Parent);

                            recycler_view.setAdapter(adapter);

                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError error) {
                            // Failed to read value
                            System.out.println("Failed to read value." + error.toException());
                        }

                    });}}

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });

    }
```

**Database Structure**
[image]

**ChildList.java**

```
public class ChildList implements Parcelable {

    private String title;


    public ChildList(String title) {
        this.title = title;
    }

    protected ChildList(Parcel in) {
        title = in.readString();
    }

    public static final Creator<ChildList> CREATOR = new Creator<ChildList>() {
        @Override
        public ChildList createFromParcel(Parcel in) {
            return new ChildList(in);
        }

        @Override
        public ChildList[] newArray(int size) {
            return new ChildList[size];
        }
    };

    public String getTitle() {
        return title;
    }

    public void setTitle(String Title) {
        this.title = Title;
    }

    @Override
    public int describeContents() {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public void writeToParcel(Parcel parcel, int i) {
        parcel.writeString(title);
    }
}
```

**Please anyone help me with this :(**

Comment: String value = getIntent().getExtras().getString("name"); is a parent name?

Comment: @Hard'kGosai It's the value that I'm fetching from another activity.

Comment: snapshot.child("title").getValue(); What is this?

Comment: @Hard'kGosai snapshot.child("title").getValue(); is the variable in ChildList class

Comment: Yaa but where did you store this value? there is no string attach with it like this String string = .snapshot.child("title").getValue().toString();

Comment: @Hard'kGosai I've added ChildList class

Comment: @Frank van Puffelen Could you please help here?

Answer (score 0):

Don't use equalTo().

Try this:

```
 DatabaseReference parentReference = database.getReference().child("Tutors");
   
    parentReference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
           
            for (final DataSnapshot snapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()){

                final String NameKey = snapshot.getKey().toString();

                if(value.equals(NameKey)){
                   //DO WHATEVER YOU WANT   
                }
             }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });
```